# Guest user rating - per user per product in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Which is the best way to allow guest users to rate a product, but only once per product. I am planning on maintaining cookies to store the rating information. Is it a good idea? Is there any better idea to achieve this?

Comment: There is no perfect idea to achieve this - if I clear my cookies, I can rate the product again.

Comment: No single 100% reliable method. If you want to limit ratings, then require an account be created before ratings can be registered.

Comment: Yes, you are right, any method is not reliable to control guest user rating. But I want to know the most reliable method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use cookies! If I clear my cookies I can rate the product again.

You can try saving the user ip address when he rates on the product. This way you can check if the user already rate on the product based on his IP address.